# Unity's pack 4 floats

Tags: c++, unity, shaders, glsl

Linked to: [GLSL pack floats into an RGBA texture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34048/glsl-pack-floats-into-an-rgba-texture)

I found EncodeFloatRGBA/DecodeFloatRGBA shader functions in Unity https://gist.github.com/hecomi/9580605

Now I try to figure out how they work. So I try them on C++
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/345f8c403d4a78f9

But I got wrong results. Also I tried that with Mathematica, and got the same wrong results.  http://www.sendspace.com/file/qmlu8b

I tried to encode {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4} - but after encode/decode got {0.0980392,0.698039,0.79649,0.93266}

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I want to pack two 4bit values into 8bit float. And search they way to do this. And that solution from Unity not work on C++, I wonder why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got wrong results due to use of numbers which are not fraction of 255. In example used 255 (max int number of 8bit), so all numbers used in encoding/decoding should be a fraction of 255.

{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4} is not a fraction of 255, it is fraction of 10 or 100 or 1000...
With values like {1/255, 2/255, 3/255, 4/255} it works ok.

So when one use pack functions like that - pay attention to this. Actually you rather store integer values (which divided by number base) than float.